# CSS animation snaps to the beginning

Tags: html, css, animation

I have this animation of a heart and I have the "beating" pretty refined.

http://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/tyqeL

Problem is that it snaps to the beginning where I want it to be continuous and smooth. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dpivs

Comment: Thanks but can you explain what you did?

Comment: just give the first and final keyframes the same value

Comment: first and final keyframes should have the same value as koala_dev said

Answer (score 5):

First and the final keyframes should have the same value. 
Add more keyframes so the animation is perfect

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dpivs)

Answer (score 1):

You are having that last jump because you have the 100% set to 400px and then start again from 100px.
Try the following:

```
 100% {
     font-size:100px;
 }
```

You can also try adding the 'alternate' for the animation direction, like this:

```
-webkit-animation:snow 1s linear infinite alternate;
```

Hope it helps.